# how would a "Flesh Forest" work?

Tags: evolution, environment, symbiosis

I have an Idea for a strange Biome called a Flesh Forest. A Flesh Forest Is an ever expanding mat of flesh ,IT has several plant like structures growing out of it that possess Teeth .the entire mat is actually a colony of organisms that grow and spread as one unit. they don't photosynthesize, and have to consume live prey to survive. how would a biome like this function? would parasites like leeches or mosquitos evolve a symbiotic relationship with it?

Comment: pick one question please.

Comment: How is this different from a [coral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coral) and from [Anthozoans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coral) in general? ("Anthozoa" means flower-animals.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing [maggots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggot)

> As with fleas and ticks, maggots can be a threat to household pets and livestock, especially sheep. Flies reproduce rapidly in the summer months, and maggots can come in large numbers, creating a maggot infestation and a high risk of myiasis (a maggot infestation of living tissue) in sheep and other animals. Humans are not immune to the feeding habits of maggots and can also contract myiasis. Interaction between humans and maggots usually occurs near garbage cans, dead animals, rotten food and other breeding grounds for maggots.
>
> When maggots turn into adult flies and start the life cycle over, numbers will grow exponentially if unchecked, but disease, natural predators and parasites keep the population under control.